# Query string to add product and apply promo code

Tags: magento-1.9

I currently have set up a query string that automatically adds a set amount of products to the users cart when they click a specific button.  I already have everything set with with the `FormKey()` and this is working as expected.

**Working -** `domain.com/checkout/cart/add/product/13/qty/6/`

I can also in an entirely different URL apply a specific promo code to the shopping cart

**Working -** `domain.com/checkout/cart/couponPost/coupon_code/PROMOCODE/`

However, I am unable to do both at the same time.  I would like to build one URL that adds specific products to the users cart and then applies the promotional code.  I would expect this URL to work....

**Does not work :(**
`domain.com/checkout/cart/add/product/13/qty/6/couponPost/coupon_code/PROMOCODE/`

But it does not.  Is there any way to accomplish what I am looking for?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.

You cannot simply pair up these URLs to form a combination of actions.

`domain.com/checkout/cart/add/product/13/qty/6/` is actually calling the [`Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php#L191) with the parameters `product = 13` and `qty = 6`

Similarly, `domain.com/checkout/cart/couponPost/coupon_code/PROMOCODE/` is actually calling [`Mage_Checkout_CartController::couponPostAction`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php#L544) with the parameters `coupon_code = PROMOCODE`.

I hope that makes sense why you cannot simply pair up the two functions, there's no way for the URL you enter to resolve to a single place in the PHP code to actually process anything.

Now, if you want you can possibly create a *new* controller action called `addProductWithCoupon` or something like that by [extending the checkout controller and defining your new action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918499/extend-magento-core-controller-checkout-onepagecontroller) but that really seems overkill.

I'm not entirely sure on your use case here, if this product is always meant to come with this discount then you should look into [catalog price rules](http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/catalog-price-rules).

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation...makes complete sense and yes extending the checkout controller would be overkill for what I am going for.  I think I will just have to tackle this from a different angle